# What is "Shield Recipe Client"?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Today, while idly glancing at my expansive list of Firefox addons, I saw something called "Shield Recipe Client" that I do *not* remember installing - or even hearing about.

A quick web search gave me nothing useful - a few conversations about viruses that may or may not have had any relevance at all, [a Mozilla wiki page](https://wiki.mozilla.org/QA/Shield) that told me it was likely a thing but told me nothing about what it *did*, and some stuff in languages other than English - and I know useful search results are running out when I see languages other than English.

I attempted to disable the addon, but nothing happened. Going back to the addons list, it had disappeared entirely. Not a trace of it, disabled or not.

What is this thing? Is it still there? Should I start wearing a tinfoil hat and/or nuke the machine from orbit?

Comment: You can browse the API where it gets its data here: https://normandy.cdn.mozilla.net/api/v1/ // The add-on source code is available here: https://github.com/mozilla/normandy/tree/master/recipe-client-addon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look at the links provided at the bottom of the Mozilla wiki page you cite. Seems like a Firefox "system addon" under development. Those addons are installed by Mozilla, and are not user-controllable. The Shield Recipe Client purpose appears to be to give Mozilla a further means of snooping around in your browser and performing actions, such as presenting survey questions, based on the results.

Comment: To be fair, they're not quite at the bottom of the page, and easy to miss if you've gone into skim-read mode. Nonetheless, I may have to invest in a tinfoil hat...

Comment: To be fair, it seems to be using Telemetry to communicate with Mozilla - this functionality requires opt-in ("Share additional data" in preferences). You can see the studies this extension is currently supposed to perform under https://normandy.cdn.mozilla.net/api/v1/recipe/.

Comment: *are not user-controllable*, those are at least disableable via about:performance…

Answer (score 4):

> Shield is a system that addresses user attrition and satisfaction in
>   Firefox by providing a fast and powerful way for Firefox to interact
>   with our users.
>
> User-facing products powered by Shield include:
>
> [Shield Studies](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/Shield/Shield_Studies)
>       Recruits users to participate in testing new features and ideas that help us validate product decisions. Our users tell us what to
>   ship.
>
> [Heartbeat](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/Shield/Heartbeat)
>       Gathers feedback from users for us to better understand what users find helpful and useful.

[(Source)](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/Shield)

Comment: Can it be removed?

Comment: It can be disabled via typing  about:config in the address bar and search for it

Answer (score 0):

> Can it be removed?

Ccleaner > Tools > Browser Plugins

- NOTE: this *had* to be an answer, I need 50 reputation to comment, I posted because I thought was very relevant.